# How to create custom widget in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am working on  birthday wish app. I want to create set reminder of my friends birthday on main screen of mobile. But I want the view of it like custom widget. Can anyone help me into how to create widget in android dynamically? That is by using coding.

Comment: You should visit this http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Answer (score 1):

```
public class DynamicImageButton extends ImageView {

    public DynamicImageButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        final Drawable d = this.getDrawable();

        if (d != null) {
            // ceil not round - avoid thin vertical gaps along the left/right edges
        final int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        final int height = (int) Math.ceil(width * (float) d.getIntrinsicHeight() / d.getIntrinsicWidth()-10);
            this.setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: This will be]